# Adding value to range of values in a list?

Tags: python, arrays

Consider the array of ranges:

```
 a = [[[4251, 4254], [4123, 4290]], [[4323, 4222], [4111, 4900]]]
```

Another one-dimensional array:

```
  b = [1324, 2745]
```

I want to create a new array by adding first element of array `b` to all the first set of ranges in array `a` and add second element of array `b` to all the second set of ranges in array `a` i.e.

```
 [[[4251+1324, 4254+1324], [4123+1324, 4290+1324]], [[4323+2745, 4222+2745], [4111+2745, 4900+2745]]]
```

How can I do it in Python?

Comment: If you do this sort of stuff a lot, take a look at Numpy: http://www.numpy.org

Comment: You probably should give a more readable example of data you are working with. Looking through 10+ lines of pure digits and braces is quite uninformative

Comment: Your new example is different from the previous one: the new one has `a` being a list of pairs, while the old had `a` being a list two sub-lists, each containing multiple pairs of numbers. This causes confusion.

Comment: What do you mean by 'ranges'? If `[4251, 4254]` is a range, then why do you call `a` 'an array of ranges'? I don't get the structure of your data..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for any length (provided `a` and `b` have the same length)

```
[[[i+b[k],j+b[k]] for (i,j) in a[k]] for k in range(len(a))]
```

In your case:

```
>>> pprint([[[i+b[k],j+b[k]] for (i,j) in a[k]] for k in range(len(a))])
[[[7880.1484209792943, 8171.6175205036743],
  [8225.6716915199249, 8378.3978601695999],
  [4729.0665464257172, 4732.276168393144],
  [5501.1899887058553, 5722.1839186014013],
  [360.55565340157807, 365.04589505745309],
  [20983.0, 20983.0],
  [217.14888548659997, 232.6226734478],
  [385.14888548659997, 400.62267344780003],
  [2823.2942485733347, 2840.4346062020377],
  [4502.0794526850004, 4700.9945330295996],
  [10417.852743984931, 10986.246567556096],
  [8191.6238503034892, 8194.8209578124479],
  [29570.28005012768, 29570.662880091983]],
 [[3250.5273987094843, 3252.7610916503263],
  [5593.4838299153871, 5596.0104208719731],
  [576.2276993911745, 622.11755144656183],
  [3188.3893120098983, 3206.7951214629902],
  [3246.2448304681798, 3250.0964343653186],
  [3272.9341862125516, 3274.8892802899418],
  [5969.1472437958755, 5971.2996518169357],
  [4255.3500559453041, 4258.126659789853]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using list comprehension in python.

```
a = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
b = [5,9]


[(x[0]+b[0], x[1]+b[1]) for x in a]
```

**Explanation**

`for x in a` - Iterate over the list `a`
`x[0]` - First element of the sub list
`x[0]+b[0]` - Add first element of each element in `a` with first element in `b`
`x[1]+b[1]` - Add second element of each element in `a` with second element in `b`

**Output**

```
[(6, 11), (7, 12), (8, 13)]
```

Comment: Your answer has been flagged in the "Low Quality" queue. I would suggest providing additional explanation as to why you believe this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

Iterate over `a[0]` and for each set of values add `b[0]` and `b[1]`.

```
new_array = [(value[0] + b[0], value[1] + b[1]) for value in a[0]]
```

output:

```
[(9202.148420979294, 10914.617520503674), (9547.671691519925, 11121.3978601696), (6051.066546425717, 7475.276168393144), (6823.189988705855, 8465.1839186014), (1682.5556534015782, 3108.045895057453), (22305.0, 23726.0), (1539.1488854866, 2975.6226734478), (1707.1488854866, 3143.6226734478), (4145.294248573335, 5583.434606202038), (5824.079452685, 7443.9945330296), (11739.852743984931, 13729.246567556096), (9513.62385030349, 10937.820957812448), (30892.28005012768, 32313.662880091983)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A. You can always iterate your `a` elements like this, but this changes elements themselves

```
for ind in range(len(a)):
    a[ind][0] += b[0]
    a[ind][1] += b[1]
```

B. You can use list comprehensions:

```
c = [[item[0] + b[0], item[1] + b[1]] for item in a]
```

C. You can use `map`:

```
c = map(lambda x: [x[0] + b[0], x[1] + b[1]], a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>a =np.array( [[4251, 4254], [4123, 4290], [4323, 4222], [4111, 4900]])
>>>b =np.array([1324, 2745])
>>>a+b


array([[5575, 6999],
   [5447, 7035],
   [5647, 6967],
   [5435, 7645]])
```

Answer (score 0):

`

```
>>> a = [[4251, 4254], [4123, 4290], [4323, 4222], [4111, 4900]] #original array
>>> b = [1324, 2745] #original array (note length of b and of individual lists of a must be same)
>>> c=[] #temporary list
>>> final_list=[]
>>> for val_a in a: #for each element(list) in a, compute c
    c=[]    #initialize temp list every time
    for index in range(len(b)): #for each element in b, compute c (note length issue mentioned above)
        c.append(val_a[index]+b[index]) #add the values and append to c
    final_list.append(c) #append c to final list


>>> final_list
[[5575, 6999], [5447, 7035], [5647, 6967], [5435, 7645]]
```

`

Glad to help